# Status of sent FCM messages

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way how to check FCM message status without implementing XMPP server (since I want to look for iOS notifications as well)?

There was a way how to do it in Google Play Console, but I don't see any specific messages where could I check according to their multicast_id or message_id.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en

I can see there only basic statistics and only of the messages that were sent from the Firebase console, not through API (which I need)

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ArolxFrXclk, there should be some new service for this, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any news on this one?

It's impossible to find issues without any feedback to help our users to receive all notifications they chose to receive. Now I can only see that all messages were sent successfully from our backend.

Comment: status that you expecting is real send or read by user? not output for post to fcm right? i also looking for this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there still isn't any announced/released alternative for the FCM Diagnostics tool.

If you in need of more information, the suggested approach as of the moment is reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with the details of your concern.

For any updates regarding it, we should expect to see an update in this [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) (see *Changes to FCM Data* section).